# How should one test caches_page?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

In a Ror3 project, how would be an elegant way to test if caches_page works as expected in my controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see if the page was cached, you can check for the file in your public folder.  Rails will output a page with a .html extension.  If you want to check a subsequent request, then maybe store the original response html (that was cached) and compare that against the subsequent request.  Or possibly use the timestamp on the cached file (although I can see that being problematic).  Are you looking for a specific implementation in rspec, cucumber, etc..?